Good notebook for multimonitor and linux
I'm currently using a samsung galaxy book (12th gen core i5, iris integrated video, cheap ssd) for software development tasks basically.
I face some screen freezes and slowdowns, probably due to running a ton of chrome tabs, 2 external monitors and some youtube/streaming tab always on. I would like to transition to a notebook that I could use for more years, bigger screens in the future, with smaller freeze situations.
I use ubuntu 24 currently, for next OS I'm unsure if I keep this one, change to some other debian flavor or try fedora workstation (last fedora I've used was around 2010, very unstable era).
I would like to know if buying a ryzen + radeon cpu/gpu would give me more stability using multiple monitors, video streaming, even light gaming, if the safest approach would be to go for a notebook with a dedicated nvidia gpu, or if I'm looking for a feature that I might not easily face using notebooks.
